# Converting equation into short Weierstrass form

Tags: elementary-number-theory, elliptic-curves, weierstrass-factorization

I have the curve $y^2 + 4y = x^3 + 3x^2 −x + 1$. I need to find a transformation of the form $X=x+a$ and $Y=y+b$
that turns this curve into the standard form of the elliptic curve: $$Y^2=X^3+AX+B.$$
I completed the square for the left side and now have $(y+2)^2= x^3 + 3x^2 −x + 5$, but I'm not sure what to do next to fix the right side. Any help would be great!

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**: Observe that
\begin{align}
&& y^2+4y&=(y+2)^2-4 \\
&\text{and}& \\
&&\qquad x^3+3x^2&=(x+1)^3-3x-1
\end{align}
Can you continue?

Comment: So if I kept going and got (y+2)^2=(x+1)^3-4x+4 and set Y=y+2 and X=x+1. Then I would get Y^2=X^3-4(X-1)+4=X^3-4X+8. With A=-4 and B=8, correct?

Comment: No, you should obtain $A=-3$ and $B=7$, if I'm not mistaken. Did you continue the second calculation replacing $-3x$ with $-3(x+1)+3?$

Comment: I did change -4x=-4(X+1), but why would you change -3x to -3(x+1)+3?

Comment: Because I need to use $X=x+1$ as a variable.

Comment: I understand that, but isn't that disregarding the −x+1  at the end of the problem on the right side?

Comment: You're right. I was sure I had taken everything into account, but, for my excuse, I made the computations directly on  screen instead of starting all the stuff from the beginning. Sorry for having made you lose time.

Comment: No worries at all, thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

You need to complete the cube in terms of $x$, this is very similar to completing the square, except that we have
$$(x+a)^3 = x^3 + 3ax^2 + 3a^2x + a^3$$
so if the coefficient of $x^2$ is $c$ then $(x + c/3)$ is the variable you should rewrite
$x^3 + cx^2 +dx + e$ in terms of so that you get
$$x^3 + cx^2 +dx + e =(x+c/3)^3 + A(x+c/3) + B$$
for some coefficients $A,B$ that you can solve for using this equation,
in your case $c/3=1$ so this should work out nicely!